# Javascript: What is wrong with this javascript implementation of merge sort?

Tags: javascript, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort using javascript.
Following is the peice of code which I find is logically sound, but fails at runtime.

```
    var a = [];
    for( i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        a.push(parseInt(Math.random()*100000));
    }
    function merge(a1, a2){
        var res = [];
        var i = 0, j = 0;
        while( i < a1.length && j < a2.length){
            if( a1[i] < a2[j] )
                res.push(a1[i++]);
            else
                res.push(a2[j++]);
        }
        while( i < a1.length )
            res.push(a1[i++]);

        while( j < a2.length )
            res.push(a2[j++]);
        return res;
    }

    function mergeSort(a){
        if( a.length <= 1 )
            return a;           
        var q = a.length/2;
        x = mergeSort(a.slice(0,q));
        y = mergeSort(a.slice(q));
        return merge(x,y);
    }
```

Whereas, the same code with a mirror change in the mergeSort(a) method gives the desired result.
The code with minor change is as follows:

```
    var a = [];
    for( i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        a.push(parseInt(Math.random()*100000));
    }
    function merge(a1, a2){
        var res = [];
        var i = 0, j = 0;
        while( i < a1.length && j < a2.length){
            if( a1[i] < a2[j] )
                res.push(a1[i++]);
            else
                res.push(a2[j++]);
        }
        while( i < a1.length )
            res.push(a1[i++]);

        while( j < a2.length )
            res.push(a2[j++]);
        return res;
    }

    function mergeSort(a){
        if( a.length <= 1 )
            return a;           
        var q = a.length/2;         
        return merge(mergeSort(a.slice(0,q)),mergeSort(a.slice(q)));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not declared these variables with 'var', they are globally scoped:

```
x = mergeSort(a.slice(0,q));
y = mergeSort(a.slice(q));
```

Comment: Thanks, 'var'ing them fixed the problems.
By this I have learnt that if I dont var them then they dont belong to local scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your x and y variables are global (because you haven't declared them local with `var`), so each time the mergeSort function is called, it will change the same variables, resulting in very unexpected behavior.

Fix:

```
function mergeSort(a){
    if( a.length <= 1 )
        return a;           
    var q = a.length/2;
    var x = mergeSort(a.slice(0,q));
    var y = mergeSort(a.slice(q));
    return merge(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 'var'ing them fixed the problems.
By this I have learnt that if I dont var them then they dont belong to local scope.